# filter entries by id retrieved from matrix block entry

Tags: templating

I've searched around and other solutions don't seem to be working I must be missing something obvious

Here's what i'm doing

```
{% set myVar = '' %}
{% for block in entry.matrixComponent %}
     {% if block.type == "matixBlockType" %}
          {% set myVar = block.matrixBlockField.ids() %}
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This seems to work when I dump myVar I get

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "10032"
```

which is indeed the id I'm looking for. I then

```
{% if entry.id not in myVar %}
    <div> {{ entry.id }} {{ Title }} not in myVar </div>
{% else %}
    <div> {{ entry.id }} {{ Title }} is in myVar {{ myVar }} </div>
{% endif %}
```

It lists out my posts in the matrix component, and where the entry.id matches myVar it still says not in myVar even though it would seem to me that it should have excluded it.

I'm not sure why it is listing the entry that matches myVar's Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do a similar test:

```
{% set myVar = ['10032'] %}

{{ dump(myVar) }}
```

That gives:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '10032' (length=5)
```

Just like yours.

```
{% set entryId = 10032 %}

{% if entryId not in myVar %}
    {{ entryId }} not in myVar
{% else %}
    {{ entryId }} is in myVar
{% endif %}
```

Outputs:

```
10032 is in myVar
```

As expected.  Changing `entryId` to something other than 10032 gives the expected "is not in myVar".

It should be noted that this line:

```
is in myVar {{ myVar }}
```

Will cause an array to string conversion error because you're telling Twig to output an array to the browser and it doesn't know how.

Comment: How would I set the string to myVar instead of the whole array? at
`{% set myVar = block.matrixBlockField.ids() %}`

Since I won't know the field id upfront normally. That way I can compare the strings later on.

Comment: changing to {% if entry.id not in myVar[0] %} gets me a templating error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following... in both your example and mine, `myVar` is set to an array with one string item in it set to "10032".

Comment: It turns out that your answer correct. We had a plugin that would essentially iterate over it setting the id back to null.

Comment: Glad you're all sorted!